# Ruby on rails: Add api to existing web application

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, api

I want to make my web service by using RoR and extend this service to mobile.

I searched how to connect RoR with android on google, However , The answer is building new ROR application with API only mode.

But I want to add API to the existing web application. How can i do this?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple workaround is to create a api folder(api/v1 incase you are also planning versioning in future) in controllers,views & helpers.

Create a controller in controllers folder & the content would be like:

```
class Api::V1::TestsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render 'show.json.jbuilder'
  end
end
```

User Jbuilder to return response in json format.
There would be a json view api/tests/show.json.jbuilder.

The content of that file would be like:

```
json.equipment do  
  json.id @contact.id  
  json.name @contact.name  
  json.type @contact.type  
end
```

and you are good to go.